# How can I check the name of the Azure AD domain that a Windows machine is joined to?

Tags: windows, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am currently using the [DsRoleGetPrimaryDomainInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676042(v=vs.85).aspx) API to get the name of the domain that the computer is joined to. However, this does not appear to work for Azure AD domains, in which case this API returns a null response.

Is there any other API that can be used locally, without reaching out to a server, to determine which Azure AD domain a computer is joined to?

Answer (score 0):

Not found the API to achieve this, however we can use the command `Net Config Workstation`(refer [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555997)) to get the actual logon domain name of a client computer.

Here is a code sample which print the relative info using C#:

```
public static string GetDoaminInfo()
{
    Process cmd = new Process();
    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    cmd.Start();

    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine("net config workstation");
    cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
    cmd.StandardInput.Close();
    cmd.WaitForExit();
    return cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a shot and see if it works.

Comment: Please feel free to let me know if you have any problem with this piece of code:)

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like `net config workstation` does not work for Azure AD domains.

Comment: It works well for me for the computer join the Azure AD. What did you get from this command?

Comment: Here's what I'm seeing. The output doesn't seem to include anything related to the Azure AD domain: https://i.stack.imgur.com/67atJ.png

Comment: Did you mean that the value(`JEREMYSPIEGAC99`) of `Logon domain` is not the domain name of Azure AD the computer join? If that, what's the domain of Azure AD the computer joined?

Comment: JEREMYSPIEGAC99 is the name of the computer. It looks like the name of the Azure AD domain is "Default Directory"? A coworker of mine set this up for testing, so I admit I don't have the complete details. I'll check with them and see.